# Jquery v1.6.4 issue for attaching click event with all anchor

Tags: jquery

this is my code which is not working when using jquery version 1.6.4 but the moment i use more upper version v1.8.3 then the same script is working.

so please have a look at my code and tell me what to change in my code if i use jquery lower version called v1.6.4.

```
<a href='test1.asp'>Test1</a>
<a href='test2.asp'>Test2</a>
<div>
  <a href='test3.asp'>Test3</a>
</div>

$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    alert('click test');
    return false; 
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/0e35fuvp/

Comment: `.on()` didn't exist in 1.6.4.  The browser console is undoubtedly telling you this.  1.6.4 is *ancient*.  Your best bet is to upgrade to something *much* newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your kind information:

> **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**
>   **version added: 1.7**

So this doesn't work. Instead, either upgrade it to `1.7`+ or use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('a').live('click', function(e) {
    alert('click test');
    return false; 
});
```

```js
$('a').live('click', function(e) {
  alert('click test');
  return false; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='test1.asp'>Test1</a>
<a href='test2.asp'>Test2</a>
<div>
  <a href='test3.asp'>Test3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mou Thanks buddy. Glad to help.

Comment: @JonathanLam Kindly have a look at this: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) `:)`

Comment: @JonathanLam Happy New Year... `:)`